# What is the difference between the access token generated in Facebook Events Manager and the "extend Access Token" in Graph API Tool?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I attempted to create an access token for setting up the conversion API in Events Manager. However, the agency's two-factor authentication generator wasn't functioning, preventing me from obtaining the access token.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evHqL.png)

As a workaround, I used the Access Token Tool in the Graph API and clicked on "extend Access Token" to generate a new access token. Fortunately, the conversion API started working, but I'm curious about the difference between these two methods.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nsYM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the difference between the two methods. The "extend Access Token" option in the Graph API tool has an expiration, while the other one has no expiration.

[See Extend Access token screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvevM.png)

[See Access token in Events Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHY7c.png)